# What excel formula should I use for if statements when cell contains text?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

[view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7skRQ.png)
I have column G (amount), column I ('paid'), and column L (Outstanding payments). I want to have column L tell me if a payment is outstanding.

If column G is filled, but column I is empty, then column L would say "Outstanding".
If both G and I columns are filled, then column L would remain empty.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=IF(AND(G2<>"",I2="Paid"),"","Outstanding")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you it works. Follow up question: In the next row (row3) where there is no input yet, the formula comes up as Outstanding still. Is there a way to let it show as empty?

what does the G2<>"" symbols stand for, can you please explain?

Comment: `G2<>""` this stands for not null (not blank). Means if G2 is not blank. You may try `=IF(OR(G2="",I2="Paid"),"","Outstanding")`